# how can i add a privacy policy section in settings bar android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Hello I want to add a toolbar with a privacy policy as a menu in which will load an xml of my privacy policy page when clicked how can I do it

Comment: Hey can you explain what you want exactly ? maybe a screen shot may help us to answer your question

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Your question must be clear and have enough details (what research for you done so far? what have you tried?) so that the community can help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50225618/16728174

add your privacy policy as menu item then decide what you want when it clicked in
 [this way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uT4eQ.png).