# Android. Toolbar menu doesn't show items

Tags: android, kotlin, toolbar

Toolbar menu doesn't show items and I can't understand why. When I start VDA-emulator it's shows menu icon, but it's blank inside. Can't add screenshot, coz Stackoverflow has some promblems with servers, as it say.

[Menu screen in VDA-emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/civn4.png)

```
Layout:
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        style="@style/ToolbarStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_toolbar"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_arrow_back"
        app:title="@string/toolbar_name" />


</LinearLayout>

Menu:

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
       <item android:title="@string/toolbar_menu_1"/>
       <item android:title="@string/toolbar_menu_2"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_comment"/>
    </menu>
```

Current appcompact version 1.5.1

Comment: Have you checked : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35648913/how-to-set-menu-to-toolbar-in-android ?

Comment: Yes, and it's not solving my situation, coz as i understand u can get this menu don't using inflater in appcompact v 1.1.0+

Comment: Solved. Problem was in dark theme for toolbar. Text was white on white background.