# Error No resource found that matches the given name attr titleTextAppearance

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-support-library

```
<style name="MyActionBarTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:titleTextAppearance">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>
        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="titleTextAppearance">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>
```

I am getting following error for titleTextAppearance for support library

```
error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'titleTextAppearance'
```

I need to change text size and typeface/font for title on ActionBar. I could change the font using [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15181195/2245895) but can not change the text size. So how do I change text size and
how can I get titleTextAppearance on support library ?

Answer (score 1):

Although I haven't tested it with `@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` as parent theme, I've used `titleTextStyle` instead of `titleTextAppearance` before as follows with `@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar"` as parent theme. You can give it a try:

```
<style name="MyActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarTitleText" parent="android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
     <item name="android:textSize">25sp</item>    
</style>
```

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: I have tried `titleTextStyle `, but it doesn't change the textzise

Comment: what parent should I use so that it has `titleTextAppearance `

Comment: Well, I don't know about that. However I have edited my answer to add `<item name="android:textSize">25sp</item> ` in the `MyActionBarTitleText`. Maybe give it a short and see if it changes the text size.