# Android set ActionBar font with CustomLayout

Tags: android, android-actionbar

after any search document i like [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8607707/how-to-set-a-custom-font-in-the-actionbar-title) to set font with custom layout for actionbar. but after use this tutorials i get an error as this:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.kol.app/ ... }: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class com.kol.app.CustomTextView
```

i dont see any class such as `CustomTextView` into that link, whats exactly `CustomTextView` in this sample?

Answer (score 1):

If you see that example you'll see `<com.your.package.CustomTextView` mentioned in the xml. This is the custom `TextView` for the `Actionbar`. You can have a class that extends `TextView` and customize it according to your needs. That's probably missing since you haven't defined it.

Comment: yes i dont have this class and i know it. my quastion is how to define that? i dont see any class like with that into that link

Comment: If you read comments there, people have given the link: https://github.com/tom-dignan/nifty/tree/master/src/com/tomdignan/nifty . You can google how to create a custom text view.