# Using a TypefaceSpan to set ActionBar title font

Tags: android

While I was researching, I found an excellent solution to setting a custom font in the ActionBar title font using `TypefaceSpan`. It is in fact, the second and most voted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8607707/how-to-set-a-custom-font-in-the-actionbar-title). The code would look something like:

```
SpannableString s = new SpannableString("My Title");
s.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan(this, "MyTypeface.otf"), 0, s.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

// Update the action bar title with the TypefaceSpan instance
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setTitle(s);
```

Looks good, but supposedly, the constructor of `TypefaceSpan` used in the example no longer exisits, checking [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/TypefaceSpan.html), the only two constructors are:

```
public TypefaceSpan(String family)
```

and

```
public TypefaceSpan(Parcel src)
```

Can I still use the new constructors to set ActionBar title fonts with the new constructors? Or do I have to move on to a new method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually that constructor came from the custom TypefaceSpan class.
You can copy the `public class TypefaceSpan extends MetricAffectingSpan` class from the answer (in the second box) to your class, and use it as the constructor.