# Unable to set action bar title with custom font

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-actionbar, textview, android-assets

I am trying to set custom font but always getting error that `textview` is null. Here is my code:

```
int titleId = getResources().getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id", "android");
TextView yourTextView = (TextView) findViewById(titleId);
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/barrett_normal.ttf");
```

Getting following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setTypeface(android.graphics.Typeface)' on a null object reference
```

This is my `onCreate()` method:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
            int titleId = getResources().getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id", "android");
            tv = (TextView) findViewById(titleId);
            tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/barrett_normal.ttf");
            tv.setTypeface(tf);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        setActionBarTitle(this.getTitle());
    }
```

Comment: show your oncreate code and xml

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8607707/how-to-set-a-custom-font-in-the-actionbar-title

Comment: @Aditya I have written only that much code in `onCreate()` method

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
SpannableString s = new SpannableString("My Title");
s.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan(this, "MyTypeface.otf"), 0, s.length(),
        Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

// Update the action bar title with the TypefaceSpan instance
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setTitle(s);
```

Check [here](https://gist.github.com/twaddington/b91341ea5615698b53b8) for  `TypefaceSpan`

Comment: the id of textview which you have in your xml..can you show your xml?

Comment: I am getting `ID` like this: `int titleId = getResources().getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id", "android");`

Comment: thats why i am asking for full activity code..did you add setcontentview method in oncreate?

Comment: I don't need to `setcontentview` in oncreate method. I just set my action bar title.

Comment: i can not see where your action bar is? please put your activity code..or else follow this http://android--examples.blogspot.in/2015/09/android-change-actionbar-title-position.html..here create textview programatically like this TextView tv = new TextView(getApplicationContext());

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107199/discussion-between-aditya-and-faisal-shaikh).