# Two actionbars are displaying, when i set custom actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I stetted custom action-bar to my activity, after adding custom action-bar it is displaying on top correctly but the default action-bar is still displaying next to custom action-bar. See the below screenshot I want to remove that black action-bar if anyone knows about this please help me here

[I refereed this link to add custom action-bar](http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/actionbar-with-custom-view-example-in-android)

Please refer below screenshot I want to remove dark action-bar

[please refer this screenshot I want to remove dark action-bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsfG6.png)

Comment: Make your app theme inherit from Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar or from Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar

Comment: Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar it showing like that @MidasLefko

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Set a Custom Font in the ActionBar Title?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8607707/how-to-set-a-custom-font-in-the-actionbar-title)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this to your styles.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item> <!-- For 2.x version  -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

and use that theme in your manifest file

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to make your activity theme in the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
        android:name="YOUR ACTIVITY NAME"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
```

set style in res/values/styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>
```

Comment: What was your solution?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, if you want a custom Action Bar as a beginner, I would recommend using the [Toolbar](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up.html#add-toolbar) widget. It works as a regular widget, that replaces the Action Bar. Once you've put the Toolbar widget in your layout, you should set it as a support action bar, in your `onCreate` method:

```
Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
```

This works only if you're using the `AppCompatActivity` as a base of your Activity. If not, you'll have to rework it.

After you've extending `AppCompatActivity` instead of `Activity`, you should change your theme, to a `.NoActionBar` version, such as `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`, so that the system does not supply an Action Bar by itself, but rather uses the one you created (you'll get an error if you don't do this).

Once you've done this, it should work!