# Change font of all list items in a list view

Tags: java, android, listview, fonts

I have set up a working custom list view array adapter code is almost similar to the one showed [here](http://www.framentos.com/en/android-tutorial/2012/07/16/listview-in-android-using-custom-listadapter-and-viewcache/) (without the cache part)

now how do I change the font of all the items to something like roboto

**edit**
i tried this

added      private Typeface textFont; before oncreate();

```
 TextView yourTextView = (TextView) listAdapter.getView(0, null, null);
      TypefacetextFont=Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(),"RobotoBoldCondensed.ttf");
     yourTextView.setTypeface(textFont);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9327053/using-custom-font-in-android-textview-using-xml

Answer (score 1):

Create a folder in the root of your project called `assets/fonts/` then paste the TTF font file (in this case roboto.ttf).

Then use that from your `adapter's getview()` method like this:

```
@Override
public View getView ( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent ) {

      /* create a new view of my layout and inflate it in the row */
      convertView = ( RelativeLayout ) inflater.inflate( resource, null );

      /* Extract the city's object to show */
      City city = getItem( position );

      /* Take the TextView from layout and set the city's name */
      TextView txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cityName);
      txtName.setText(city.getName());

      /* Take the TextView from layout and set the city's wiki link */
      TextView txtWiki = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cityLinkWiki);
      txtWiki.setText(city.getUrlWiki());

      Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/roboto.ttf");

      txtName.setTypeface(face);
      txtWiki.setTypeface(face);

      return convertView;
}
```

**EDIT :**

Change this line,

```
TypefacetextFont=Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(),"RobotoBoldCondensed.ttf");
```

with,

```
textFont=Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(),"RobotoBoldCondensed.ttf");
```

Comment: my listadapter is setup differently..     TextView yourTextView = (TextView) listAdapter.getView(0, null, null);
     Typeface textFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(),"Roboto-BoldCondensed.ttf");
     yourTextView.setTypeface(textFont);

Answer (score 0):

in xml:

```
android:typeface
```

or in java:

```
setTypeface
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Typeface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Typeface.html) you can change the font of your text, keep desire `font` ttf file in your assets folder, access and set to your desire view, just like below:

```
TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.custom_font);  
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "roboto.ttf");  
txt.setTypeface(font);
```

For more help check [Quick Tip: Customize Android Fonts](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/customize-android-fonts/)

Comment: where? can you post your logcat?

Answer (score 0):

Copy your font in to your `assest` folder and put this code inside of your custom array adapter

```
    TextView yourTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.yourid);
    Typeface textFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"YourFont.ttf");
    yourTextView.setTypeface(textFont);
```

It should work.

**EDIT**

`private Typeface textFont;`
Declare

```
@Override
public void onCreate(){

textFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"YourFont.ttf"); }
```

in `OnCreate()` or `OnStart()`

and just use your custom font in your `getView()`

```
yourTextView.setTypeface(textFont);
```

Comment: have you initialised the `TypeFace` in `onCreate`. In Your code  `TextView yourTextView = (TextView) listAdapter.getView(0, null, null);`
      `Typeface textFont=Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(),"RobotoBoldCondensed.ttf");
     yourTextView.setTypeface(textFont);`  remove this line `Typeface textFont=Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(),"RobotoBoldCondensed.ttf");` and put it in onCreate.

Comment: sorry. what do you mean. And also post your error log. It will help to find the exact problem.