# How to use findViewsWithText()

Tags: android, textview

Here is my problem :

I want to be able to change the font of several TextView at the same time in my android application.

Changing it in the XML files seems to be complicated, extending TextView class brings memory problems (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376250/custom-fonts-and-xml-layouts-android)).

So i tried to change the font in the java code, like that :

```
Typeface robotoThin = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/Roboto-Thin-webfont.ttf");
TextView index_slogan = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.index_slogan));
index_slogan.setTypeface(robotoThin);
```

That's working great, but i'd rather to select more than one Textview, with `findViewsWithText`, but i can't understand how it works...

Some help would be appreciated.

EDIT :

Ok so it didn't work because it's been implemented since API level 14, and i was trying on API level 10...

Do you know any other functions to find multiple views?

Comment: what don't you understand ?

Answer (score 2):

**1-** how to set Costume font ,the best way to set costume font is to do that programmatically and the best and easier way to do that , register `public` `static` `Typeface` in ur Api or main class for example I've `Api.class` content every costume things i made

add

`public static Typeface myfont;`

then when i call the `Api.class` on my activity creation set the font type

`Api.myfont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/Roboto-Thin-webfont.ttf");`

now you can use `Api.myfont` for every textview or Edittext or any other views for example

```
editText.setTypeface(Api.myfont);
myradio.setTypeface(Api.myfont);
mytextview.setTypeface(Api.myfont);
mycheckBox.setTypeface(Api.myfont);
```

**2 -** `findViewsWithText()` will fetch the view's has `android:contentDescription="blabla"`

Comment: one more thing to pay attention regarding the `findViewsWithText` is that it needs you to create the input View Array object before you call the function. If you send a null object, the method will fail

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to create a custom `TextView` and in to set the font there. That way you can even create custom styleables, that define what font to use.

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14954799/2910492) answer on how the view should look and [this](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html#customattr) documentation about custom styleables.