# Set font face in android

Tags: android, android-fonts

I want to change some textview font-face to external font and i do something like this :

```
typeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/bkoodak.ttf");
tv1.setTypeface(typeFace);
tv2.setTypeface(typeFace);
tv3.setTypeface(typeFace);
...
```

But this form is't nice to me.
Is there some way to do this better?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9327053/using-custom-font-in-android-textview-using-xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a better way.

But you have to create your own derived TextView that apply the TypeFace. And use it in your XML Layout.

Refer to this question for more details:
[How to make a custom TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477336/how-to-make-custom-textview)

Answer (score 1):

You can create own TextView class:

```
public class MyTextView extends TextView {

        public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);
            init(attrs);
        }

        public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
            init(attrs);

        }

        public MyTextView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            init(null);
        }

        private void init(AttributeSet attrs) {
            if (attrs != null) {
                TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
                        R.styleable.MyTextView);

                Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext()
                        .getAssets(), "fonts/bkoodak.ttf");
                setTypeface(myTypeface);

                a.recycle();
            }
        }

    }
```

and use it in you layout:

```
 <yourpackage.MyTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use create a class and use it everywhere.

For example:

FontChanger Class:

```
public class FontChanger
{
    private Typeface typeface;

    public FontChanger(Typeface typeface)
    {
        this.typeface = typeface;
    }

    public FontChanger(AssetManager assets, String assetsFontFileName)
    {
        typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(assets, assetsFontFileName);
    }

    public void replaceFonts(ViewGroup viewTree)
    {
        View child;
        for(int i = 0; i < viewTree.getChildCount(); ++i)
        {
            child = viewTree.getChildAt(i);
            if(child instanceof ViewGroup)
            {
                // recursive call
                replaceFonts((ViewGroup)child);
            }
            else if(child instanceof TextView)
            {
                // base case
                ((TextView) child).setTypeface(typeface);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

onCreate of your activity :

```
FontChanger fontChanger = new FontChanger(getAssets(), "font.otf");
fontChanger.replaceFonts((ViewGroup)this.findViewById(android.R.id.content));
```