# Custom Font in ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

So I am trying to set a custom font (hello.ttf) which is already in the assets folder to a ListView. Below is my java and xml file.

faListFragment.java

```
public class faListFragment extends Fragment {


    public faListFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fa_list, container, false);

        String[] faList = { "One",
                            "Two",
                            };

        ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listFa);


        ArrayAdapter<String> listviewAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
              getActivity(),
              android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
              faList
       );




        listView.setAdapter(listviewAdapter);

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return view;
    }

}
```

and this is my fragment_fa_list.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.me.hello.faListFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listFa" />
</FrameLayout>
```

I have tried several ways of adding the font, but cant quite seem to grasp how to go about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create one layout xml in layout folder. In that layout xml you have to user custom textview with custom font.

For CustomTextView Link : [Using custom font in android TextView using xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9327053/using-custom-font-in-android-textview-using-xml)

```
ArrayAdapter<String> listviewAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
              getActivity(),
              R.layout.row_item, R.id.text ,
              faList
       );
 listView.setAdapter(listviewAdapter);
```

**Edit :** 
**My CustomTextView Class**

```
public class MyTextView extends TextView {

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public MyTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        if (!isInEditMode()) {
            Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf");
            setTypeface(tf);
        }
    }

}
```

**row_item.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:orientation="vertical">




    <pakagename.MyTextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"

        android:text="CEO"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="16dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I didn't quite follow this.

Comment: For CustomFont of TextView, You have to do this. If you find something new please suggest me too.

Comment: would appriciate if you were a bit more detailed than that. I am very new to java and android development.

Comment: at the end of (R.layout.row_item, R.id.text) there should be a (,) or else the code produces a syntax error. otherwise this works perfectly. pls correct so i can accept the answer