# How do I create a reusable < Style /> resource that has a custom font?

Tags: android

I know how to do it programatically as such:

```
    TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.custom_font);
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Chantelli_Antiqua.ttf");
    txt.setTypeface(font);
```

But how does one do this as a style that can be inherited and extended? I just want to declare a TextView to have a common < Style /> tag

< TextView /> has an attribute called "typeFace" but valid values are only "normal", "sans", "serif", and "monospace"

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:typeface

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376250/custom-fonts-and-xml-layouts-android

This post should help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the answer but I figured out a very sad workaround.

Extend the TextView component class

In the constructor of the subclass, fire off the code

```
TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.custom_font);
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "Chantelli_Antiqua.ttf");
txt.setTypeface(font);
```

...yuck

Comment: Yeah. Your still doing this in Java code. Your just making it fire in a different area.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you are not able to do this. You can not load a font in via xml and make it into a style. However, I sure hope that someone is able to prove me wrong on this because I would love to have this available.