# Using custom Textview in Style

Tags: android, customization, textview

I have one custom `TextView` whose name is `TextViewPlus`. I want to add style for my custom `TextView`. when i write this to `styles.xml` it hasn't work. The error is :

> error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr
>   'foo:customFont'.

this is styles.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources
    xmlns:foo="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example">

    <style name="textstyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textSize">50sp</item>
        <item name="foo:customFont">Fonts/BZar.ttf</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**Notice that I get my custom TextView from [Custom fonts and XML layouts (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376250/custom-fonts-and-xml-layouts-android)**

Comment: did you create attrs for customFont?

Comment: read this article http://kevindion.com/2011/01/custom-xml-attributes-for-android-widgets/ this might enlighten you.

Comment: i have exactly this problem.any solution?

Answer (score 2):

I resolve this issue by delete the namespace tag.
change:

```
<style name="textstyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textSize">50sp</item>
    <item name="foo:customFont">Fonts/BZar.ttf</item>
</style>
```

to:

```
<style name="textstyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textSize">50sp</item>
    <item name="customFont">Fonts/BZar.ttf</item>
</style>
```