# Android - How to set a custom font for whole app

Tags: android, text, fonts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to set font for entire Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711858/is-it-possible-to-set-font-for-entire-application)

I need to set a custom font (.ttf format) for whole app, how can i do it?
From Manifest or XML would be the best option if it is possible

Comment: Just because it is marked duplicate, one can't provide a better answer: Use the calligraphy library to achieve this. It even changes the font of toasts.

Comment: wouldn't you just use https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**EDIT Sept 2014:**

For anyone still seeing this old terrible answer, the real, good answer is here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16883281/1154026

---

**OLD:**

Your best bet would be this:

[Customize Android Fonts](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/customize-android-fonts/)

So

```
    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.custom_font);
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "yourfont.ttf");
    text.setTypeface(font);
```

With your .ttf in the root of the "assets" folder.

Comment: This works great, but if I have a ListView how can i change the font of the row? I suppose is possible to do through XML

Comment: That solution doesn't seem to work anymore on Android 5.0
Any other option?

Comment: @AndreaMarioLufino Setting this typeface in your adapter to all the textViews you got would work. Let's say you have `textview1,textview2` and `textView3`than you should just use setTypface(yourfont) on them. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 11):

You could do it like this.
Create a custom textview and use that one everywhere

```
public class MyTextView extends android.widget.TextView
{

    public MyTextView(Context context)
    {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        if (this.isInEditMode()) return ;

        final TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.SomeStyle);
        final String customFont = a.getString(R.styleable.SomeStyle_font);

        //Build a custom typeface-cache here!
        this.setTypeface(
            Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), customFont)
        );  
    }
}
```

Add this to attrs.xml

```
<declare-styleable name="SomeStyle">
    <attr name="font" format="string" />
</declare-styleable>
```

Then in your theme, do this:
This will make sure all the textviews will use the style MyTextView

```
<item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/MyTextView</item>
```

And now we can define your custom font using your custom attribute in this style.

```
<style name="MyTextView" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
    <item name="font">MyPathToFontInAssets.ttf</item>
</style>
```

So whenever you use MyTextView in the project, it will have your custom font.

**IMPORTANT:** Typefaces are not cached, so if you plan on using this code, you should also build a custom typeface-cache so you can re-use the custom typeface for all textviews. This will significantly speed-up the application!

**UPDATE:** As Amir was saying, this is almost the same as [Custom fonts and XML layouts (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376250/custom-fonts-and-xml-layouts-android/7197867#7197867) but i also use android styling to automatically use it on all textviews in the app.

Comment: Hi! Its showing error in this line  `<item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/MyTextView</item>` ** A 'type' attribute is required for <item>** What I have to do now?

Comment: I cleared errors by adding `type="string"`

Comment: _Typefaces are not cached, so if you plan on using this code, you should also build a custom typeface-cache_  how to build a cache?

Comment: You can have a static singleton class somewhere with a hashmap that holds references to the loaded typefaces. Be sure to clear it when your app is closed!

Comment: <item name="font">MyPathToFontInAssets.ttf</item>

how can i set the path here? any example? thanks~

Comment: What you type here is just appended to the assets path. If you want a folder there just type `<item name="font">myfolder/myfont.ttf</item>`

Comment: how can we revert back to default.   I am doing something like this:     http://pastebin.com/qJqbEBqE

Answer (score 10):

Cerate a TextView subclass and use it everywhere

```
    public class RobotoTextView extends TextView {

    public RobotoTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    public RobotoTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public RobotoTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        if (!isInEditMode()) {
            Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf");
            setTypeface(tf);
        }
    }

}
```

usage

```
<com.test.RobotoTextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
```

in java code you can cast it to TextView

Answer (score 7):

```
TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.custom);
    Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                                          "fonts/Verdana.ttf");

    tv.setTypeface(face);
```

put the font file in the fonts folder in /res/

Like my answer if it is helpful...

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the TextView as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7197867/1545562) and set your typeface on that then use it in whole app.