# How to set a downloadable font for a whole application as default font?

Tags: android, android-fonts, android-downloadable-fonts

In my previous projects, I have used [Calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy) library to set a font for a whole application. But it requires storing font file in assets which makes APK size bigger. Now I am wondering is it possible to set a [downloadable font](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/downloadable-fonts.html) as default for a whole application.

I could set a downloadable font for only ONE TextView.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"
    android:fontFamily="@font/lato"
    android:text="@string/large_text" />
```

Yes, I know I could create [MyTextView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12282315/6126123) class and set downloadable font programmatically. But I do not think it is a good idea as text can be anywhere in EditText, Spinner item, Toast.

So my question is how to set a downloadable font for a whole application as default font?

Answer (score 1):

To apply a font set in XML everywhere in your app, create a theme in your `themes.xml` and set `android:fontFamily` in it.

```
<style name="ApplicationTheme">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/lato</item>
</style>
```

Set this theme to your application in the Manifest

```
<application
    android:name=".App"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:theme="@style/ApplicationTheme">
...
</application>
```

and as long as you are not using style inheriting from system styles like

```
<style name="CustomButton" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless">
```

your font will get applied to all TextViews, EditTexts, Spinners, Toasts, etc.

Answer (score 0):

[A library to help with custom fonts and text sizes](https://github.com/mattsilber/font-utils)

The goal of this library is to allow your app to support multiple FontFamilies (e.g. lato, roboto, etc.) with their own styles (e.g. normal, bold, italic) in an easily-configurable way.

Comment: But this library does not work for whole application

Answer (score 0):

```
public final class FontsOverride {

    public static void setDefaultFont(Context context,
            String staticTypefaceFieldName, String fontAssetName) {
        final Typeface regular = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
                fontAssetName);
        replaceFont(staticTypefaceFieldName, regular);
    }

    protected static void replaceFont(String staticTypefaceFieldName,
            final Typeface newTypeface) {
        try {
            final Field staticField = Typeface.class
                    .getDeclaredField(staticTypefaceFieldName);
            staticField.setAccessible(true);
            staticField.set(null, newTypeface);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


public final class Application extends android.app.Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        FontsOverride.setDefaultFont(this, "DEFAULT", "MyFontAsset.ttf");
        FontsOverride.setDefaultFont(this, "MONOSPACE", "MyFontAsset2.ttf");
        FontsOverride.setDefaultFont(this, "SERIF", "MyFontAsset3.ttf");
        FontsOverride.setDefaultFont(this, "SANS_SERIF", "MyFontAsset4.ttf");
    }
}
```