# What is the equivalent of "android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light" in Java code?

Tags: android, typeface

My question is quite simple:

In every of my textview, I am currently using the attribute

```
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
```

to provide a gorgeous look on post HC devices.

Unfortunately, this doesn't work with every widget and for my Spinners, I need to overwrite the Adapter.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    //You can use the new tf here.

    if(convertView == null || convertView.getTag() == null) {
        // new view - populate 
        convertView = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, parent, false);
        convertView.setTag(new Object());
    }

    CheckedTextView spinner_text=(CheckedTextView) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
    //Typeface should be set here...
    return spinner_text;
    }
}
```

So, is there a way to get exactly the same result by code?

PS: No, I don't want to put a typeface in asset folder, I just want to use system one.

Answer (score 181, accepted):

It should be possible with `setTypeface()` and `Typeface.create()`:

```
convertView.setTypeface(Typeface.create("sans-serif-light", Typeface.NORMAL));
```

See [Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Typeface.html#create%28java.lang.String,%20int%29):

> Create a typeface object given a family name, and option style
>   information. If null is passed for the name, then the "default" font
>   will be chosen. The resulting typeface object can be queried
>   (`getStyle()`) to discover what its "real" style characteristics are.

Note that excessively using `Typeface.create()` is bad for your memory, as stated in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376250/custom-fonts-and-xml-layouts-android#comment11263047_7197867). The [suggested Hashtable](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9904#c7) is a good solution, but you have to modify it a little since you don't create your typeface from an asset.

Comment: Please beware of memory issues if you have many spinner items -- I updated my answer a little.

Answer (score 52):

> Android 4.1 (API Level 16) and Support Library 26 and higher

If you are using res -> font folder, you can use like this

```
  val typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(Context, R.font.YOUR_FONT)
  TextView.setTypeface(typeface)
```

Answer (score 25):

Dynamically you can set the fontfamily similar to android:fontFamily in xml by using this,

```
For Custom font:

 TextView tv = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.select_item_title));
 Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/mycustomfont.ttf"); 
 tv.setTypeface(face);

For Default font:

 tv.setTypeface(Typeface.create("sans-serif-medium",Typeface.NORMAL));
```

These are the list of ***default font*** family used, use any of this by replacing the double quotation string **"sans-serif-medium"**

```
FONT FAMILY                    TTF FILE                    

1  casual                      ComingSoon.ttf              
2  cursive                     DancingScript-Regular.ttf   
3  monospace                   DroidSansMono.ttf           
4  sans-serif                  Roboto-Regular.ttf          
5  sans-serif-black            Roboto-Black.ttf            
6  sans-serif-condensed        RobotoCondensed-Regular.ttf 
7  sans-serif-condensed-light  RobotoCondensed-Light.ttf   
8  sans-serif-light            Roboto-Light.ttf            
9  sans-serif-medium           Roboto-Medium.ttf           
10  sans-serif-smallcaps       CarroisGothicSC-Regular.ttf 
11  sans-serif-thin            Roboto-Thin.ttf             
12  serif                      NotoSerif-Regular.ttf       
13  serif-monospace            CutiveMono.ttf
```

"mycustomfont.ttf" is the ttf file. ***Path*** will be in *src/assets/fonts/mycustomfont.ttf* , you can refer more about default font in this [Default font family](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39535475/what-is-the-default-font-family-in-android#39536066)

Answer (score 22):

In my opinion there is still a way to apply system fonts programatically on TextView **without having any memory issue** and that is using **`textview.setTextAppearance`** method :

```
<style name="styleA">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">?android:attr/textColorPrimary</item>
</style>
<style name="styleB">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-light</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">?android:attr/textColorTertiary</item>
</style>


if(condition){
    textView.setTextAppearance(context,R.style.styleA);
}else{
    textView.setTextAppearance(context,R.style.styleB);
}
```

Comment: `android:fontFamily` requires API 16.

Comment: Use `TextViewCompat.setTextAppearance(textView, R.style.styleA)`.

Answer (score 14):

**Option 1** - API 26 and higher

```
// Jave
Typeface typeface = getResources().getFont(R.font.myfont);
textView.setTypeface(typeface);

// Kotlin
val typeface = resources.getFont(R.font.myfont)
textView.typeface = typeface
```

**Option 2** - API 16 and higher

```
// Java
Typeface typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.myfont);

// Kotlin
val typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.myfont)
```

Check the full expiation at [Android Developers Guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml#kotlin).

Answer (score 6):

It would be possible by using

`setTypeface(Typeface tf, int style)` method of `TextView` class.

`spinner_text.setTypeface(Typeface.SANS_SERIF,Typeface.NORMAL);`