# How to change fontFamily dynamically though Java code

Tags: android, textview, font-family, android-fonts

As per https://stackoverflow.com/a/13329907/3286489, we could change the fontFamily of the TextView. But how could I set that using Java code? I can't find the API.

Comment: if you wants to change the fontTypeFace of textview specifically the you may provide a style attribute to TextView type at styles document and add the font family to that, after that you dont need to setTypeFace to any of the textview.

Comment: Found my answer through http://stackoverflow.com/a/14344132/3286489

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `setTypeface()` method on `TextView` in java code .

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset( getAssets(), "fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf" );
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview1);
tv.setTypeface(font);
```

Please visit the API [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTypeface(android.graphics.Typeface))

Hope you got your answer !!!

Comment: Almost there, the better answer is in http://stackoverflow.com/a/14344132/3286489

Comment: @Elye Would suggest to use `createFromAsset()` and not `()` as it is more efficient and saves from you from using extraneous memory... :) ..

Comment: I meant not `create()`