# What is the default font family in Android?

Tags: android, fonts, font-family, roboto

Starting in API 16, Jellybean Roboto was introduced as available font family to use. See whats "new" in Android 16 [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.1.html#Fonts).

Specifying `android:fontFamily="sans-serif"`(Roboto in API 16+) on a `TextView` the default `fontFamily` of the `TextView`?

Is

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

equivalent to

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif" />
```

?

From [Material design typography website](https://material.google.com/style/typography.html#):

> "Roboto and Noto are the standard typefaces on Android and Chrome."

From [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roboto),

> "Roboto is a sans-serif typeface family developed by Google as the
>   system font for its mobile operating system Android."

I do not see in the docs what the default `fontFamily` of Android is. See references:

- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#fontFamily
- [Valid values for android:fontFamily and what they map to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19691530/valid-values-for-androidfontfamily-and-what-they-map-to)
- https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.1.html#Fonts
- http://alvinalexander.com/photos/android-roboto-fonts-examples

Comment: The two items you entered are equivalent. While they don't call `sans-serif` Roboto, it is actually is the default font-family in Android.

Comment: Why is this downvoted?

Comment: @Weava Do you have a link to docs supporting that?

Comment: Nope, but Jared Rummier gave a much better answer than I could've :)

Comment: For reference: *"In Android, Noto fonts are the default typefaces for all languages not covered by the original Roboto."* - [source](https://fonts.google.com/knowledge/using_type/language_support_in_fonts#noto).

Answer (score 84, accepted):

There is no documentation on d.android.com for font family names. However, if you look at AOSP, the default fonts are loaded in `android.graphics.*`. The [FontListParser](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/graphics/java/android/graphics/FontListParser.java) loads the default fonts from `/system/etc/fonts.xml` (Android 5.0+) or `/system/etc/system_fonts.xml` (Android 4.1). The default fonts are loaded in [Typeface#init](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/graphics/java/android/graphics/Typeface.java).

The two XML files have some documentation. The first font is the default font. You can pull /system/etc/fonts.xml from your device. A device manufacturer or custom ROM may change the default system fonts.

**fonts.xml** (API 21+)

> NOTE: this is the newer (L) version of the system font configuration,
>     supporting richer weight selection. Some apps will expect the older
>     version, so please keep system_fonts.xml and fallback_fonts.xml in sync
>     with any changes, even though framework will only read this file.
>
> All fonts withohut names are added to the default list. Fonts are chosen
>     based on a match: full BCP-47 language tag including script, then just
>     language, and finally order (the first font containing the glyph).
>
> Order of appearance is also the tiebreaker for weight matching. This is
>     the reason why the 900 weights of Roboto precede the 700 weights - we
>     prefer the former when an 800 weight is requested. Since bold spans
>     effectively add 300 to the weight, this ensures that 900 is the bold
>     paired with the 500 weight, ensuring adequate contrast.

**system_fonts.xml** (API 16-20)

> System Fonts
>
> This file lists the font families that will be used by default for all supported glyphs.
>     Each entry consists of a family, various names that are supported by that family, and
>     up to four font files. The font files are listed in the order of the styles which they
>     support: regular, bold, italic and bold-italic. If less than four styles are listed, then
>     the styles with no associated font file will be supported by the other font files listed.
>
> The first family is also the default font, which handles font request that have not specified
>     specific font names.
>
> Any glyph that is not handled by the system fonts will cause a search of the fallback fonts.
>     The default fallback fonts are specified in the file /system/etc/fallback_fonts.xml, and there
>     is an optional file which may be supplied by vendors to specify other fallback fonts to use
>     in /vendor/etc/fallback_fonts.xml.

If you parse the fonts.xml file, you can find which font family uses which typeface (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29533686/1048340)):

```
╔════╦════════════════════════════╦═════════════════════════════╗
║    ║ FONT FAMILY                ║ TTF FILE                    ║
╠════╬════════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════╣
║  1 ║ casual                     ║ ComingSoon.ttf              ║
║  2 ║ cursive                    ║ DancingScript-Regular.ttf   ║
║  3 ║ monospace                  ║ DroidSansMono.ttf           ║
║  4 ║ sans-serif                 ║ Roboto-Regular.ttf          ║
║  5 ║ sans-serif-black           ║ Roboto-Black.ttf            ║
║  6 ║ sans-serif-condensed       ║ RobotoCondensed-Regular.ttf ║
║  7 ║ sans-serif-condensed-light ║ RobotoCondensed-Light.ttf   ║
║  8 ║ sans-serif-light           ║ Roboto-Light.ttf            ║
║  9 ║ sans-serif-medium          ║ Roboto-Medium.ttf           ║
║ 10 ║ sans-serif-smallcaps       ║ CarroisGothicSC-Regular.ttf ║
║ 11 ║ sans-serif-thin            ║ Roboto-Thin.ttf             ║
║ 12 ║ serif                      ║ NotoSerif-Regular.ttf       ║
║ 13 ║ serif-monospace            ║ CutiveMono.ttf              ║
╚════╩════════════════════════════╩═════════════════════════════╝
```

Comment: Can anyone explain how each TTF file was mapped as the default for each font family? For example, for `sans-serif`, why is it that `Roboto-Regular` was the TTF file used? I see many files listed in this font family. Why was this particular one chosen over the others?

Comment: Okay, I see that you used a weight of 400 as a threshold to determine the default font (looking over your code in the other post). Why 400 though?

Comment: @coolDude, weight value for "normal" is 400. According to  https://www.w3.org/TR/css-fonts-4/#font-weight-absolute-values