# What is the default font used in android if developer didn`t specify any

Tags: android, fonts, default

I want to know what is the default font that is used by Android OS for my app if i didn`t specify any font to be used.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39535475/what-is-the-default-font-family-in-android) post didn`t help

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the devices that run **stock-Android**, according to [Material Design Guidelines](https://material.google.com/style/typography.html#):

> Roboto is the standard typeface on Android.

But in case that you use languages not covered by `Roboto` (check the same link to see all languages covered by it), the typeface will be switched to `Noto`

> Noto is the standard typeface for all languages on Chrome and Android for all languages not covered by Roboto.

That being said, the actuals fonts differ depending on the place where they are used (see below some examples from the same guideline)

> App bar
>   Title style, Medium 20sp
>
> Buttons
>   English: Medium 14sp, all caps
>   Dense: Medium 15sp, all caps
>   Tall: Bold 15sp

For the pre-Lollipop devices, the same rules apply, but you might notice some changes between different versions since Google refined `Roboto` as the time passed.

However, all the above are true only for **stock-Android**, the rest of them having a predefined typeface/font based on the device or manufacturer. As Eli Sadoff stated, most of these devices let the user pick a default font which will be used across all apps (without exceptions), even if you have a custom font for your app.

PS: Make sure to read everything form the provided link because you'll find more useful information.

Answer (score 4):

The default font varies phone to phone. The default font can be set by the user on certain varieties of Android (like Samsung phones), and on others the default font is set and cannot be changed by the user. There is no single default font.