# Roboto font support in Lollipop+ & pre-Lollipop devices

Tags: android, android-fonts, roboto

I wanna use the following font in my application
 - Roboto Medium
 - Roboto Regular
 - Roboto Light

As per Material design documentation, Roboto font is available by default.

Do I need to do anything specific to support for pre-Lollipop devices, other than setting the font as custom.

Is it good practice to set this roboto as custom font since some manufacturers provide changing the font (which I don't want to support in my app) ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40133793/what-is-the-default-font-used-in-android-if-developer-didnt-specify-any/40137379#40137379

Comment: Here is a library to help you use [Roboto](https://github.com/elmargomez/typer) easily.