# On Android, how do I get the font type selected on device and also know if it's the default one?

Tags: android, fonts

Attached below is a screenshot of the fonts on my device. 
[image: fonts on my device]

Here is the requirement:

- if the user selects the default font, the app should use Roboto
- if any other font is selected, use the selected font on the app.

Examples:

1. if selected font = Rosemary, app. font = Rosemary
2. if selected font = Default, app. font = Roboto

(The default font on the system may or may not be Roboto)

How do I programmatically get the font selected on the system, and also know if it's the default one or not?

I know that if I use Typeface.DEFAULT, it would give me the selected font. But I would also like to know if it's the Default font (as seen in the attached screenshot).

Comment: I've updated my answer. please check if it suits your needs

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look into this [Typeface](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Typeface.html). This class provides tools so that you can know which font/typeface is selected for against which type.

For e.g. Look at [defaultFromStyle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Typeface.html#defaultFromStyle(int))

```
Typeface.defaultFromStyle(int style)
```

where the value of Style is an Integer and the values varies from

```
int: Value is NORMAL, BOLD, ITALIC, or BOLD_ITALIC
```

---

**Edit 1**

After doing a bit of research I found that Typeface doesn't provide the font name. Then i found this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39536066/2299040) this gives very useful information and it leads to another [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29533686/2299040) which has a custom **FontListProvider** and states that the first font will be the default Font. If you use that custom class then it would be very easy to find the default font.

```
final List<FontListParser.SystemFont> fonts = FontListParser.safelyGetSystemFonts();
String[] items = new String[fonts.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < fonts.size(); i++) {
    Log.e("Font",fonts.get(i).name);
}
```