# Reusing Navigation Bar font in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, uiappearance

We need to add specific buttons to the left hand side of the NavigationBar in a Xamarin Forms View.

That is currently only supported via a TitleView because ContentPage.ContextItems all appear on the right hand side. TitleView means implementing the whole of the Navigation Bar.

I want my TitleView to look as close as possible to the platform specific Navigation Bar. Does anyone know how to get hold of the

- Platform title font size
- Platform foreground colour that would be used for the Title

I've tried all the NamedFont values and whilst they are close they aren't correct.

I have created a custom Label for used in the TitleView. Below are details of what I tried in the respective renderers

**iOS:**

I had hoped I could use `UINavigationBar.UINavigationBarAppearance` to obtain the right Font name, size and Color but I cannot get a populated instance of that. I have tried

```
UINavigationBar.AppearanceWhenContainedIn(typeof(UINavigationController))
```

but the Appearance class was not populated

**Android**

I have tried inflating the standard ActionBar layout and reusing the TextView in there but was unable to get that to work

Comment: In iOS you could check the system fonts from https://developer.apple.com/fonts/system-fonts/

Comment: Seeing as I said we're using Xamarin Forms are you suggestion a Custom Renderer, perhaps a NavigationBarLabel control? DO you know if there is an Android way of getting those fonts? I did look at the XF code in Github but couldn't follow it. I'll try again later

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39535475/what-is-the-default-font-family-in-android

Comment: Lucas that SO question does not show me the Font Size ad Family that is being used for the Standard TitleView

Comment: Check the link in the question .