# What is the default font used to display emojis on Android?

Tags: android, fonts

I found a list of the default fonts in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39535475/what-is-the-default-font-family-in-android) but I'm not able to find which font is used for displaying emojis (if there is one).

Comment: I believe it's Noto Emoji <https://github.com/googlefonts/noto-emoji>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’ve looked far and wide for an answer to this, e.g., the androidx docs:

https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/text-and-emoji/emoji2

At the end of the day, the `emoji2` library loads Noto Emoji but could load other fonts, too.

The font name in use (can also be used in CSS `font-family` declarations) is
**Noto Color Emoji Compat**.