# Custom font in android ( for WHOLE application)

Tags: android, performance, fonts

I have this android code with many classes each with different Views. We can go to settings and change their font according to the font selected. Right now only the pre-installed android fonts are available. Is there a way to slightly tweak my code so that I can add a .ttf file and provide that as an option in fonts.
I don't want to make large changes in code.

Comment: not really, he's asking on how to change the font for the whole application at once

Comment: Here's the more appropriate one then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376250/custom-fonts-and-xml-layouts-android

Comment: The way you can do that with minimal changes in your code is creating a class which take as params your current activitie's view and change all view's typeface, but doing that you should be careful, because instantiating lots of font's variables in your app will make it crash at some point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use typeface to set custom font for the text in textview. So whenever you required custom font for your textview you can use the below.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />
<TextView android:id="@+id/text"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textColor="#FFF"
          />
 </LinearLayout>
```

The code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private TextView text;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    Button b= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            text.setText("This is a custom toast");
            Typeface typeFace =  Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/kn.ttf");
            text.setTypeface(typeFace);

        }

    });

}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, works as wanted!

Comment: You can also check this https://github.com/lisawray/fontbinding

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't, unless you will use your own View with custom font.