# Changing the font of a textview within a widget?

Tags: java, android, fonts, widget

Is there a way to change the font in a widget? I've seen some questions/answers on here but some say it can't be done. Others say it can be done but then don't provide much information. I'm talking about a custom font that I put in my assets folder. The font I want to use is Roboto from the design guidelines.

I mostly want to ask because of the other questions stating it isn't possible. I have the Google Currents widget on my Nexus 7 that uses the Roboto font on it's widget so surely it is possible?

The TextView I want to change is well, just a textview. It has no formatting/styles on it at the moment. The only thing I really need is the font changed to Roboto light.

I would appreciate some advice on how to do this. Thanks.

I actually plan on open sourcing the widget I am making here so it could help others too.

Comment: does calling setTextSize() not work for you?

Comment: I've not tried it.. TextSize not for size..? Have I missed something very easy?

Comment: no I misread the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is there a way to change the font in a widget?

Yes, but unfortunately you can only use the system fonts. You can use the Roboto fonts natively on Android 4.1+ like this though:

```
android:fontFamily="sans-serif"           // roboto regular
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"     // roboto light
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed" // roboto condensed
```

The only way to use Roboto on previous versions for your Text would be to create a Bitmap and draw your Text on Canvas like this:

```
    Bitmap myBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas myCanvas = new Canvas(myBitmap);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/myFont.ttf");

    paint.setTypeface(font);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setColor(...);
    paint.setTextSize(...);
    myCanvas.drawText("Hello World", x, y, paint);
```

And then set it like this to your `RemoteView`:

```
rViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.myImageView, myBitmap);
```

Comment: what about custom fonts. I download custom.ttf store it in assests folder use the same for test view

Comment: Custom fonts. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634245/how-to-add-external-fonts-to-android-application

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15991521/custom-font-in-android-for-whole-application/15991573#15991573

Comment: @Raghunandan OP is talking about custom fonts in AppWidgets.

Comment: @Ahmad ok. If its appwidgets we can't use custom fonts?

Comment: @MichalPalczewski You can't set custom fonts in AppWidgets.

Comment: @Ahmad thanks for the clarification. Well then he can use available system fonts right?

Comment: @Ahmad 4.1+ only? Damn... That's a shame. Just seen your edit. I presume the bitmap thing will only work if you have the text already set out though? Hence the "Hello world" part? Mine changes based on a database so I guess I should stick with the first bit

Comment: You can of course load your text from a database and then rebuild the bitmap, but this approach with bitmaps can get unnecessarily complicated, so yes, I would stick with the   `setTextViewText(...)` approach.

Comment: @Ahmad Yeah fair enough. I appreciate the help! +1 and Marked as answer.