# Is there any way to use fontFamily on 4.0 devices?

Tags: android, android-layout

`android:fontFamily` was applied for devices > than 16. That means 4.1 have this attribute but doesn't 4.0.4 for example.
So I'm trying to use

```
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
```

To get a holo font. It works cool in 4.2 but not on 4.0.4, it's showing some default font.

Is there anyway to set it by xml? Or do I've to set it by code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is doing it on your code! Place the font in your assets folder, create and set it on your text view:

```
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview03);
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Molot.otf");
text.setTypeface(tf);
```

It is possible to do it on the xml. It's a lot harder thought. You have to extend the TextView  component and use it on your xml instead of the typical android TextView.

Take a look on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376250/custom-fonts-and-xml-layouts-android) for more details on how to achieve that.

Comment: Both ways need too many things to be changed each time you place a TextView. So I guess I will use the code way. Was praying to get a easy way... Thanks anyways!

Comment: That's what i did. But i had just a few textviews. If you have too many, it's a good idea to extend the class and replace every textview with your own.