# How do you change the font of the list on a navigation drawer?

Tags: android, custom-font, navigation-drawer

There's no TextView for me to setType in the Activity and setting it through a custom class and XML is a real memory drag so is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

> How do you change the font of the list on a navigation drawer?

The same way you "change the font" of any `ListView`: by customizing your rows from your `ListAdapter`. For example, for an `ArrayAdapter`, you create a subclass, override `getView()`, and apply your `setTypeface()` call there.

> setting it through a custom class and XML is a real memory drag

And your proof of this is... what, exactly?

Comment: No proof, just this thread ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376250/custom-fonts-and-xml-layouts-android/7197867?noredirect=1#comment-11263047 )but if you say it doesn't I believe you. getView returns CreateViewFromResource and that's the method where the logic really happens, so should I override that too?

Answer (score 0):

> There's no TextView for me to setType in the Activity and **setting it
>   through a custom class and XML is a real memory drag** so is there
>   another way?

No it's absolutely fine to define custom `TextViews`, since the `TextView` has to set a Typeface [either way](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java#L1319).

Comment: I really dont know much of the internals of Android to havean opinion about it. I was just following this comment"One thing to note is that it will generate dozens and dozens of TypeFace objects and eat up memory. There is a bug in pre4.0 Android that doesnt free up TypeFaces properly. The easiest thing to do is create a TypeFace cache with a HashMap. This brought memory usage in my app down from 120+ mb to 18mb. code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9904 " made on thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376250/custom-fonts-and-xml-layouts-android/7197867?noredirect=1#comment-11263047