# View inflate Exception error while writing code for custom font in textview in my application

Tags: android, android-custom-view, inflate-exception

i am using following class for custom font for my textview. 
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.Typeface;
    import android.util.AttributeSet;
    import android.widget.TextView;

```
public class MyTextView extends TextView{

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public MyTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),
                                               "DIEHLD_DECO.ttf");
        setTypeface(tf);
    }

}
```

this the xml file containing my textView

```
<com.example.application1.views.MyTextView 
        android:textSize="27.0sp" 
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" 
        android:gravity="top" 
        android:layout_gravity="center" 
        android:id="@+id/tname" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        />
```

while running the app my logcat shows following error.

```
10-31 16:09:33.249: E/AndroidRuntime(17017): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.application1/com.example.application1.MySlideShows}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class com.example.application1.views.MyTextView
10-31 16:09:33.249: E/AndroidRuntime(17017):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
10-31 16:09:33.249: E/AndroidRuntime(17017):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
10-31 16:09:33.249: E/AndroidRuntime(17017):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:149)
10-31 16:09:33.249: E/AndroidRuntime(17017):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1300)
10-31 16:09:33.249: E/AndroidRuntime(17017):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-31 16:09:33.249: E/AndroidRuntime(17017):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
10-31 16:09:33.249: E/AndroidRuntime(17017):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
10-31 16:09:33.249: E/AndroidRuntime(17017):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-31 16:09:33.249: E/AndroidRuntime(17017):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-31 16:09:33.249: E/AndroidRuntime(17017):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
10-31 16:09:33.249: E/AndroidRuntime(17017):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
10-31 16:09:33.249: E/AndroidRuntime(17017):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-31 16:09:33.249: E/AndroidRuntime(17017): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class com.example.application1.views.MyTextView
10-31 16:09:33.249: E/AndroidRuntime(17017):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
10-31 16:09:33.249: E/AndroidRuntime(17017):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
10-31 16:09:33.249: E/AndroidRuntime(17017):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
10-31 16:09:33.249: E/AndroidRuntime(17017):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
10-31 16:09:33.249: E/AndroidRuntime(17017):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
10-31 16:09:33.249: E/AndroidRuntime(17017):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
10-31 16:09:33.249: E/AndroidRuntime(17017):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:258)
10-31 16:09:33.249: E/AndroidRuntime(17017):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
10-31 16:09:33.249: E/AndroidRuntime(17017):    at com.example.application1.MySlideShows.onCreate(MySlideShows.java:73)
10-31 16:09:33.249: E/AndroidRuntime(17017):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5020)
10-31 16:09:33.249: E/AndroidRuntime(17017):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
10-31 16:09:33.249: E/AndroidRuntime(17017):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
10-31 16:09:33.249: E/AndroidRuntime(17017):    ... 11 more
10-31 16:09:33.249: E/AndroidRuntime(17017): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
10-31 16:09:33.249: E/AndroidRuntime(17017):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
10-31 16:09:33.249: E/AndroidRuntime(17017):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
10-31 16:09:33.249: E/AndroidRuntime(17017):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
10-31 16:09:33.249: E/AndroidRuntime(17017):    ... 22 more
10-31 16:09:33.249: E/AndroidRuntime(17017): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made
10-31 16:09:33.249: E/AndroidRuntime(17017):    at android.graphics.Typeface.<init>(Typeface.java:175)
10-31 16:09:33.249: E/AndroidRuntime(17017):    at android.graphics.Typeface.createFromAsset(Typeface.java:149)
10-31 16:09:33.249: E/AndroidRuntime(17017):    at com.example.application1.views.MyTextView.init(MyTextView.java:26)
10-31 16:09:33.249: E/AndroidRuntime(17017):    at com.example.application1.views.MyTextView.<init>(MyTextView.java:17)
10-31 16:09:33.249: E/AndroidRuntime(17017):    ... 25 more
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made or memory leak for custom TextView loading font](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20942671/runtimeexception-native-typeface-cannot-be-made-or-memory-leak-for-custom-textv)

Comment: have you directly put your custom font file in assert or put on fonts folder inside assert ?

Comment: i have put custom font file in assests folder

Comment: please check my ans problem due to context reference.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

You have required to your current context reference instead of getContext() so just pass your context reference to intit method from all constructor.

```
public class MyTextView extends TextView{


    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context);
    }

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public MyTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context) {
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"DIEHLD_DECO.ttf");
        setTypeface(tf);
    }

}
```