# Using custom font for a Scientific Calculator app in Android Studio

Tags: android, custom-font

```html
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:labelFor="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
    android:clickable="true">

    <com.example.girikarnal.trial.CalculatorButtonTextView
        android:id="@+id/acbutton"
         android:text="@string/AC"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/calc"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="73dp" />

    <com.example.girikarnal.trial.CalculatorButtonButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:text="@string/xsquare"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="#ffbfa2ff"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:labelFor="@android:color/black" />

<com.example.girikarnal.trial.CalculatorButtonButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:text="@string/hyp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="84dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

```html
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       CalculatorButtonTextView jtv;
        Button jb;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        jtv=(CalculatorButtonTextView)findViewById(R.id.acbutton);
        jb=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        Typeface tf;
        tf=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/casiofont.ttf");
        jb.setTypeface(tf);

    }
```

```html
public class CalculatorButtonTextView  extends TextView {

    // Constructors
    public CalculatorButtonTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }
    public CalculatorButtonTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }
    public CalculatorButtonTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    // This class requires casiofont.ttf to be in the assets/fonts folder
    private void init() {
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),
                "fonts/casiofont.ttf");
        setTypeface(tf);
    }
```

```html
public class CalculatorButtonButton extends Button {
    public CalculatorButtonButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public CalculatorButtonButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public CalculatorButtonButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public CalculatorButtonButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        init();
    }
    private void init() {
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),
                "fonts/casiofont.ttf");
        setTypeface(tf);
    }
}
```

```html
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">fx-991ES</string>

    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="AC">C</string>
    <string name="calc">r</string>
    <string name="xsquare">d</string>
    <string name="hyp">c</string>

</resources>
```

I am building a scientific calculator in Android Studio and i want to use fonts from a ttf file i got from a casio website, I placed them in the assets/fonts folder as suggested in some in other pages but when i run the app i get the error "native type face cant be made".Also other doubt is there was a file called keyboard supplied with the font file i downloaded ,is this the map key like "c=ac". I am a newbie please help me.
I have added the link to download the ttf file.
"http://edu.casio.com/education/fontset/"
Download the font for **fx-ES plus series**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each Button or TextView (I like to make my buttons using textviews because they are more flexible) you need to set your Typeface.

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),
            "fonts/ES03.TTF");
myButton.setTypeface(tf);
```

Since you have a lot of buttons it might just be easier to make a custom button class that extends TextView:

```
public class CalculatorButtonTextView extends TextView {

    // Constructors
    public CalculatorButtonTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }
    public CalculatorButtonTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }
    public CalculatorButtonTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    // This class requires ES03.TTF to be in the assets/fonts folder
    private void init() {
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),
                "fonts/ES03.TTF");
        setTypeface(tf);
    }

}
```

And then in your xml file to do something like this for each button/textview:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/key_41"
    style="@style/AppTheme.KeyLayoutStyle"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <com.mycalculatorapp.CalculatorButtonTextView
            android:id="@+id/tvKey41"
            style="@style/AppTheme.KeyTextStyle"
            android:text="@string/key_41" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm cutting and pasting from [another project](https://github.com/suragch/aePronunciation/blob/master/res/layout/fragment_keyboard.xml) to save time so the actual styling isn't shown here. Explore that project more to see how I applied the styles and strings if that is a question.

Finally, using FontForge to view the font you can see that the normal letters and numbers are overwritten with the calculator symbols.

[image]

Finally you'll do something like

myButton.setText("C");

to get the AC button glyph. (Or better yet do it in your xml files.)

This is the method I used to display special symbols/glyphs that weren't supported by the system fonts.

**Update**

Since it still wasn't working for you I decided to try it out myself.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_calculator);

    Button jb=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    Typeface tf;
    tf=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/casio.ttf");
    jb.setTypeface(tf);

    //jb.setText("Cc"); 
}
```

Xml:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Cc"
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:textSize="30dp" />
```

This worked for me both by setting the text in xml and in code. I could see both the **AC** and the **hyp** glyphs. So I think you must have a different problem if you are only getting the capital versions. Try restarting with a fresh project.

By the way, you may want to beware of memory leaks if you are instantiating a TypeFace in a custom Button or TextView and create a separate class for the TypeFace as is talked about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21395261/3681880). If you don't make a custom class you can just apply the same typeface to all your buttons in onCreate.

Comment: thanks it worked but there was a problem.. caps C is for "AC", small c is for "hyp" function. But when i enter c it gives "AC" only. How to solve this problem.

Comment: I have added the code, Please tell me how to rectify this problem.

Comment: I don't see anything off hand that should make it not work. I can only suggest that you do more testing. Is this the only one that doesn't work? Or do all the lower case letters not work?

Comment: all the lower cases are not working,even if i input only the lower case then also it displays the symbol for upper case.

Comment: Do the symbols appear if you type with the font in Word/LibreOffice/etc? Do the lower case letters appear if you use a system font in your app without applying the TypeFace?

Comment: yes the symbol appear well in the ms word and openoffice libra,and yes the lower case letters are seen when i type it without the typeface, any way i can force it to be small or caps letters when sending to the typeface class created as per your suggestion..

Comment: I tried working on it myself and could see both upper and lowercase. See my update.

Comment: I started a new project and it worked,yes the link was helpful i guess calling it from textview will take up more memory i will change it, thank you so much ...