# How to apply custom font in calendar android

Tags: android

I'm working on some android application and I need to show a calendar with a custom font, I figured out how to apply it on textViews but still can't figure out a way to do that for the calendar. Any help?

Comment: see this way 1 in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45960527/4797289).its easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't it advisable to add fonts as assets to your app on android(though it is very possible and widely used). Luckily Google introduced the downloadable fonts in Android 8.0 (API level 26) and Android Support Library 26. I cant describe the whole thing here but you can read more about it [here on the Android website](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/downloadable-fonts.html) 
Downloadable fonts are a cleaner way to add fonts in my opinion.

Comment: I want to apply that to a CompactCalendarView, do you know how it works?

Comment: I have not seen anywhere it has been applied on the stock calenderView but I think you can achieve this with a custom calendarView.

Comment: do you have any documentation about how to achieve it using customCalendarView? @kidrocker

Comment: Check out [this post](https://inducesmile.com/android/how-to-create-android-custom-calendar-view-with-events/) for the custom calenderView. You can then add the font to individual textViews and buttons using Google's guide on fonts stated earlier

Comment: I've seen that article before, and it's a lot of work to do, I just need to change the font on my calendar and I can't follow all that due to my timeline for this app, so this won't help a lot, thanks anyways, I'm really grateful for your help.