# How to use the Typeface and find out the font I am going to use

Tags: android, textview, android-typeface

I am trying to add a `icon` to my `textview`. My java code for the corresponding fragment is:

```
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {

    public BlankFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),
                "fonts/weathericons-regular-webfont.ttf");
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       ....
       TextView name_sunrise = rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv_sunr);
       //name_sunrise.setText();  Here I want to put an icon from tf
```

My xml for tv_sunr is defined as:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_sunr"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/tv_sunrt"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tv_sunrt"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/iv_image"
        android:paddingLeft="10sp"
        android:text="@string/sunrise"
        android:textSize="20sp"></TextView>
```

And the text I am trying to replace is             `android:text="@string/sunrise"`
defined in `strings` as:

```
<string name="sunrise">SunRise</string>
```

The question is twofold:

1. How to add the `ttf` to the textview
2. How to find the actual item in the ttf file I am looking to use (e.g. in this case, how to find the font for sunrise)

I am using [this ttf from github](https://github.com/erikflowers/weather-icons/blob/master/font/weathericons-regular-webfont.ttf).

I am following [this tutorial](https://www.androstock.com/tutorials/create-a-weather-app-on-android-android-studio.html), but stuck here.

**UPDATE**
Hi, from the weather icon, I have found that the icon I want to use is named as `wi-sunset`. The problem is how I will use that icon. Kindly help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376250/custom-fonts-and-xml-layouts-android/48642116#48642116

Answer (score 0):

inside your `onCreateView` , you can set the font like this

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),
            "fonts/weathericons-regular-webfont.ttf");
TextView name_sunrise = rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv_sunr);
name_sunrise.setTypeface(tf);
```

Comment: Yes...thats what I have done, but that does not solve my 2nd question. WHat is my icon name? how to set that up?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android Studio 3.0, then You need to create the directory with font. in font directory you can put your .ttf file

After that use the below code:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_shop_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_semibold"
    android:text="Hair Cut + Hair Spa"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

create `font` folder inside your `res` folder and put your string files on `font` folder.

You can define font for your views like below.

**XML :**

```
   android:fontFamily="@font/your_font" //no need to mention your file type (ttf,otf)
```

**Java :**

```
Typeface t =ResourcesCompat.getFont(activity, R.font.your_font);
```

Thanks